# Way to remove text through CSS or JavaScript/jQuery *without* causing alignment to fail?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

https://jsfiddle.net/ut1mgcLb/1/

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="object1">

    <div class="snax-voting-container-body">
  
        <div class="snax-voting snax-voting-positive snax-voting-large" data-snax-item-id="297">
            <div class="snax-voting-score">
                <strong>6203</strong> points
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="snax-voting-upvote snax-vote snax-vote-up snax-guest-voting" title="Upvote" data-snax-item-id="297" data-snax-author-id="0" data-snax-nonce="6bb412040e"><span class="snax-vote-icon snax-vote-icon-caret"></span> Upvote</a>
            <a href="#" class="snax-voting-downvote snax-vote snax-vote-down snax-guest-voting" title="Downvote" data-snax-item-id="297" data-snax-author-id="0" data-snax-nonce="6bb412040e"><span class="snax-vote-icon snax-vote-icon-caret"></span> Downvote</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href=" https://themeforest.net/item/bimber-viral-buzz-wordpress-theme/14493994 ">
  
  
  
  <img id="postTB" src=" https://i.imgur.com/Nf57W2G.jpg"></a><a href=" https://themeforest.net/item/bimber-viral-buzz-wordpress-theme/14493994 "> 25 Delicious Things To Cook In September (themeforest.net)</a><img alt="" src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/9f221658beaba2ee853f978fa48f49c2?s=40&amp;r=g&amp;d=retro" srcset="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/9f221658beaba2ee853f978fa48f49c2?s=40&amp;r=g&amp;d=retro 2x" class="avatar avatar-40 photo" height="40" width="40">
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#postTB{
  width:10%;
}

.snax-voting-container-body {
  display: inline;
      align-items: center;vertical-align: middle;
position: relative;
}

.snax-voting {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.snax-voting a {
  display: block;
}

.snax-voting-upvote {
  order: 0;
  
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/69alhp8.png');
    background-size: 10px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%; 
    height: auto;
    content:"";
    transform: translateX(50%);
}
.snax-voting-score {
  order: 1;
}
.snax-voting-downvote {
  order: 2;
  
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/YklTOzm.png');
    background-size: 10px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%; 
    height: auto;
    content:"";
    transform: translateX(50%);
}
#postTB{
  position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

and my (commented out) jQuery:

```
//var $div = $('.snax-voting-container-body');

//$div.text($div.text().replace('points', ''))

//$div.text($div.text().replace('upvote', '^'))
```

Whenever I try to use that jQuery, for some reason it just causes everything to fall out of alignment.

Is there a way to remove the 'points', 'upvote', and 'downvote' text while keeping everything vertically centered?

I initially did color:transparent to hide the text before realizing how bad it looked when someone highlighted the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **visibility** property of CSS. This will not cause alignment issues as it will take up space in the dom unlike the **display** property.

```
.hide-element {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Add this class to your element and add/remove class from js on conditional values.

```
$div.toggleClass('hide-element', boolean_condition);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are retreiving the text content with `$div.text()`, it gets all text without the HTML tags.

Then when you are injecting it back into the div with `$div.text( ... )`, it sets the result as the text content of the div, actually clearing all inside of it. Because what you inject has been stripped of the HTML part, you loose your HTML tags.

try with:

```
$div.html($div.html().replace('points', ''))

$div.html($div.html().replace('upvote', '^'))
```

Howhever, take care not to replace text that belongs to your classes or tags that would correspond to "points" or "upvote" in the process.

Comment: That does work to keep everything aligned, but it does cause a problem of deleting the arrow images and the actual buttons so they can't be clicked anymore on my site. Is there another approach that conserves the buttons? (unfortunately I can't just go in and change the html)

Comment: Ah I see you edited your question, now it's clearer, the accepted answer is the best way to do it then. The code in my answer shouldn't have affected images, the code provided is obviously not the full one, where there is probably dynamically loaded elements and events attached that don't support dynamical changes. good luck for the rest of your work